# Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API message on emulator

Tags: opengl-es, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing an Android application for Android 2.2.

When I run a program that uses OpenGL ES 2.0 on emulator I get the following error:

called unimplemented OpenGL ES API

But if I run the same program on a physical device with Android 2.2 it works perfectly.

What's happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably that you tried to do something that isn't implemented in the emulator.

Testing stuff on the Android emulator isn't a very nice experience for any kind of application, and for games or other real-time apps, or anything that uses multitouch, you should opt for testing on the device as much as possible anyway, IMHO. So not much lost there.

Answer (score 2):

The emulator doesn't support OpenGL.  You need to run and debug the application on a real Android device.

Comment: The emulator doesn't support OpenGL ES 2.0, but it does supports ES 1.1, I'm not sure how robust that support is however.